# Add a prefix to each key in Json dictionary list using comprehension

Tags: python, json, dictionary-comprehension

I am looking to add a prefix to each key in a `JSON` so my message looks as follows, with `tmp.` prefix

```
[{'tmp.p.class': 'B', 'tmp.timestamp': '2020-08-07 09:00:00'}, {'tmp.p.class': 'A', 'tmp.timestamp': '2020-08-07 09:00:05'}]
```

---

```
import json      
x = [{'p.class': 'B', 'timestamp': '2020-08-07 09:00:00'}, {'p.class': 'A', 'timestamp': '2020-08-07 09:00:05'}]
data = json.dumps(x)

y = [{'tmp.'+k: v for k, v in d.items()} for d in data]
print(y)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "./prog.py", line 5, in File
> "./prog.py", line 5, in AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute
> 'items'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to serialize the python object to a string. You can directly perform the modification on the list `x`.

```
y = [{"tmp." + k: v for k, v in d.items()} for d in x]
```